# Why do the "iodbc" and "libmyodbc" packages conflict with each other?

Tags: mysql, database

When I install iodbc the libmyodbc package is removed, and I don't understand why.  Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Its not entirely clear why they conflict. The relationship is declared in libmyodbc, as such:

```
Breaks: libiodbc2, odbcinst1debian2 (<< 2.2.14p2-3), unixodbc (<< 2.2.14p2-3)
```

But confusingly, its also recommending libiodbc2!

```
Recommends: libodbc1 | libiodbc2
```

The changelog only mentions this way back in 2002 in an update from Debian:

```
myodbc (2.50.39-1) unstable; urgency=low

  * New upstream release
  * Add a package relationship for unixodbc | libiodbc2.

 -- Steve Langasek <vorlon@debian.org>  Sun, 24 Feb 2002 23:01:06 -0600
```

This seems like a bug, and its probably worth asking the maintainer for an explanation via a bug report filed with

```
`ubuntu-bug myodbc`
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears myodbc is specifically an ODBC wrapper for mysql, while iodbc is a generalized ODBC wrapper for all kinds of DBs, so a conflict seems logical.

Evidently somehow one database connector is used to configure another...which evidently if they conflict, it isn't.

See [the other answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/177436/58612) for more information, and on how to file a bug.

Comment: Why would this be moved to serverfault? This is a question about packages in Ubuntu, and not even server related packages.. these are client packages! The question has plenty of detail.

Comment: Thanks for answering @SpamapS; we're not all "server-y" guys ;), and the above appeared to be the consensus in the chatroom at the time (which is why this was posted CW). I will edit the answer.